# INSERT INTO table Column and Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

just a quick question . IS it possible to Select A column and a Custom value into a table. I have a table of software  and a table of installed software. I'm using the domain role value of the machine its installed on to specify a software type of server or PC. There are multiple types of server and PC however and I would like to distill these values into one numerical value that can be linked to another table. For example the result would be

```
¦SoftwareName¦SoftwareType¦     ¦DomainRoleID¦Type  ¦
¦SofWare1    ¦1           ¦     ¦1           ¦PC    ¦
¦SofWare2    ¦2           ¦     ¦2           ¦Server¦
¦SofWare3    ¦1           ¦
¦SofWare4    ¦2           ¦
```

As I need to select multiple Records from a table and insert a different type value I was wondering if I could do this during an insert into clause much like

```
INSERT INTO tblSoftware (SoftwareName, SoftwareType)
SELECT (SoftwareName, '2')
FROM tbl2
WHERE domainRole > 1
```

Is this even possible or will I need to perform an Update after I get the data over? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I have been, Can't get the syntax right and it just struck me that I might be being foolish.

Comment: Hmm nothing major, Apparently. Just strikes me as odd that I'm selecting a column and a value. Not Used this query before and In my head it shouldn't work. Its like a mix between a regular insert and a Select. Just doesn't make too much sense to my Budding SQL brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
INSERT INTO tblSoftware (SoftwareName, SoftwareType)
SELECT
       SoftwareName
     , CASE WHEN Type = 'PC' 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE '2'
       END AS Type
FROM tbl2
WHERE domainRole > 1
```

Comment: Worked a Charm, Changed it a bit to fit what I needed but went great. I've not long come across CASE, its good to know I'm learning!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the brackets,

```
INSERT INTO tblsoftware 
            (softwarename, 
             softwaretype) 
SELECT softwarename, 
       CASE 
         WHEN type = 'PC' THEN 1 
         ELSE '2' 
       END AS Type 
FROM   tbl2 
WHERE  domainrole > 1
```